# Android: Insert data (images) from database and show it in GridView

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gridview

Im having trouble applying the icons to the respective position on the GridView. I already managed to apply the different names from database but i still didnt realize how to do the same with the images.

When i run the app the 3 icons are created but the icon is the same (the first one bank1.png) for the 3 categories. I tried some stuff like *icon.setImageResource(alsc.get(position).getIcon());* but didnt work because it always says that can due that to a String. I would apreciate some help. thanks

**SavingsCatA (activity)**

```
package com.mutesoft.faxpro;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mutesoft.savings.SavingsCat;
import com.mutesoft.savings.SavingsCatDataSource;
import com.mutesoft.sqlitedb.MySQLiteHelper;

public class SavingsCatA extends Activity implements
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    MySQLiteHelper mySqlHelper;
    SavingsCatDataSource scDataSource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        mySqlHelper = new MySQLiteHelper(this);
        scDataSource = new SavingsCatDataSource(mySqlHelper.db);


        insereNaAppDadosPreDefinidosSavingsCat();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void insereNaAppDadosPreDefinidosSavingsCat() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<SavingsCat> savingItems = scDataSource.getAllSavingsCat();

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, savingItems));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<SavingsCat> alsc;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<SavingsCat> alsc) {
            context = c;
            this.alsc = alsc;

        }

        // ---returns the number of images---
        public int getCount() {
            return alsc.size();
        }

        // ---returns the ID of an item---
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        // ---returns an ImageView view---
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
            TextView label = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            label.setText(alsc.get(position).getName());
            ImageView icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.album_image);
         // icon.setImageResource(alsc.get(position).getIcon());


            LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) icon.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = 70;

            icon.setLayoutParams(params);

            return row;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View v, int pos, long id) {

        // ImageView icons = new ImageView(this);
        // icons.setAlpha(0);

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(this, "weeeeeeeeeeeeee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

**MySQLiteHelper**

```
package com.mutesoft.sqlitedb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.mutesoft.savings.SavingsCat;
import com.mutesoft.savings.SavingsCatDataSource;

public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "savings.db";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // SAVINGS
    public static final String TABLE_SAVINGSCAT = "savingscat";
    public static final String COL_SAVINGSCAT_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COL_SAVINGSCAT_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COL_SAVINGSCAT_ICON = "icon";


    public SQLiteDatabase db;

    Context context;

    public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        db = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // SAVINGS
        String createSavingsCat = "create table " + TABLE_SAVINGSCAT + " ( "
                + COL_SAVINGSCAT_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + COL_SAVINGSCAT_NAME + " text, " + COL_SAVINGSCAT_ICON
                + " text);";

        db.execSQL(createSavingsCat);

        // função para criar icons e secções pre-definidas para SAVINGS
        criaDadosPreDefinidosSavingsCat(db);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {      

    }


    public void criaDadosPreDefinidosSavingsCat(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        SavingsCat sc1 = new SavingsCat();
        sc1.setName("Banks");
        sc1.setIcon("bank1.png");

        SavingsCat sc2 = new SavingsCat();
        sc2.setName("Piggy Banks");
        sc2.setIcon("piggybank.png");

        SavingsCat sc3 = new SavingsCat();
        sc3.setName("Others");
        sc3.setIcon("moneyjar.png");

        SavingsCatDataSource scDataSource = new SavingsCatDataSource(db);

        scDataSource.insertSavingsCat(sc1);
        scDataSource.insertSavingsCat(sc2);
        scDataSource.insertSavingsCat(sc3);
    }

}
```

**SavingsCat**

```
package com.mutesoft.savings;

public class SavingsCat {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String icon;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setIcon(String icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
}
```

**SavingsCatDataSource**

```
package com.mutesoft.savings;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;

import com.mutesoft.sqlitedb.MySQLiteHelper;

public class SavingsCatDataSource {
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public SavingsCatDataSource(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public SavingsCat getSavingsCat(long id) {
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
                + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SAVINGSCAT + " WHERE "
                + MySQLiteHelper.COL_SAVINGSCAT_ID + " = " + id, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursorToSavingsCat(cursor);
    }

    public ArrayList<SavingsCat> getAllSavingsCat() {
        ArrayList<SavingsCat> alp = new ArrayList<SavingsCat>();

        Cursor cursor;

        cursor = db.rawQuery(
                "SELECT * FROM " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SAVINGSCAT, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            alp.add(cursorToSavingsCat(cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();

        return alp;
    }

    public void insertSavingsCat(SavingsCat sc) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COL_SAVINGSCAT_NAME, sc.getName());
        values.put(MySQLiteHelper.COL_SAVINGSCAT_ICON, sc.getIcon());

        db.insert(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SAVINGSCAT, null, values);
    }

    public void updateSavingsCat(SavingsCat sc) {
        String query = "UPDATE " + MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SAVINGSCAT + " SET "
                + MySQLiteHelper.COL_SAVINGSCAT_NAME + " = '" + sc.getName()
                + "', " + MySQLiteHelper.COL_SAVINGSCAT_ICON + " = '"
                + sc.getIcon() + "', " + MySQLiteHelper.COL_SAVINGSCAT_ID
                + " = " + sc.getId();

        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    public void eliminaSavingsCat(long id) {

        db.delete(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_SAVINGSCAT,
                MySQLiteHelper.COL_SAVINGSCAT_ID + " = " + id, null);
    }

    public SavingsCat cursorToSavingsCat(Cursor cursor) {
        SavingsCat sc = new SavingsCat();

        sc.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
        sc.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        sc.setIcon(cursor.getString(2));

        return sc;

    }

}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="center" >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lay"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dip"
        android:listSelector="@layout/selectors"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/album_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bank1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textColor="#D0D0D0"
        android:text="ola" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: and where do you have `xxxx.png` file ?

Comment: on "res\drawable-mdpi". The app is already getting one of the images (bank1.png) from the MySQLiteHelper. Im not able to set the images on the correct grid location due to their position.

Comment: then you should store only `xxxx` in db and use `Resources.getIdentifier(...,...,"xxxx")` to get int ID of this resource ... and thi DI can be used with `setImageResource`

Comment: sorry. i didnt understood it very well =/

Comment: can you please show me that bit of code? it doesnt have to be all complete, just for me to know where to start or what to fix. thanks

Comment: ok. i really couldnt manage to do it